# xamppのhttpd.confを編集したらapacheが動かなくなった

Tags: apache, xampp

悩み
・xampp-apache-confフォルダのhttpd.confを編集しapacheのstartを押すとエラーが出て動かない。
編集部分
・httpd.confファイル末尾に

```
Alias / "/xampp/htdocs/作成したプロジェクト名/public/"
<Directory "/xampp/htdocs/作成したプロジェクト名/public/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverrise all
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

これを記述しただけです。
C:の直下にxamppを置いているのでパスが間違っている可能性はないと思います。

解決方法の分かる方、よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpd.confの文法チェックをしてみてください。`C:\`直下ということはWindowsでしょうから、以下の記事を参考にしてください。

参考： [Windows版Apacheのconfigテスト](https://qiita.com/rsuzuki/items/22493421b57ee37646df)

ヘルプの確認

```
> httpd.exe -h
```

文法チェック

```
> httpd.exe -S
> httpd.exe -t
```

Comment: タイプミスをしていました。ありがとうございました。